# Does this matrix have a square root, and what is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $$M=\Biggl(\matrix{1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&1}\Biggr)$$

does $M$ have a square root?

I believe that $M$ corresponds to a positive linear transformation, because it is a self-transpose, and has all non negative eigenvalues 2, 0, and 1 (according to numpy.linalg.eig). Because of this it should have a square root,
However, scipy.linalg.sqrtm says that the square root is
$$\Biggl(\matrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\Biggr)$$
when I square that matrix in python, it gives:
$$\Biggl(\matrix{\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}}\Biggr)$$

Is there a bug with my brain, or with numpy/scipy?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2Fsqrt%282%29%2C0%2C1%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2Fsqrt%282%29%2C0%2C1%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%7D%5E2) says squaring that matrix does give you back $M$. Can you show your work?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I just mutiplied the matrix by itself in the code

Comment: Is it possible that you're inadvertently computing the elementwise square?

Comment: ok, so scipy.linalg.sqrtm returns an array, even if you give it a matrix

Comment: @Bungo so yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I see the problem. In programming languages there are two "squaring" operations on matrices. One squares each individual entry, the other is actual matrix multiplication.

You squared each individual entry of $M^{1/2} := \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

If you use matrix multiplication, you'll get $M^{1/2}M^{1/2} = \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = M$.

Comment: yes, and this was happening because sqrtm was returning an array, when I expected a matrix (because I originally gave it a matrix)

Comment: It's the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).